# Error running SoapUI test in docker container with "ddavison/soapui" docker image

Tags: docker, centos, virtual-machine, soapui

I have SoapUI downloaded on a CentOS VM where I have created a SoapUI project that runs correctly. Now, I downloaded the 'ddavison/soapui' docker image inside of a different CentOS VM that does not have SoapUI. I started the container and went to "localhost:3000/" and see the instructions to curl the project to localhost:3000. I have tried with the project I made and a sample soapUI project that came with the download. Neither work, and they both get the same error. 
I run the command:

`curl --form "project=@/home/Documents/Sample-REST-Project-soapui-project.xml" http://localhost:3000/`

I get the following output:

```
 ================================
    =
    = SOAPUI_HOME = /opt/SoapUI
    =
    ================================
    2018-12-13 12:49:06,639 [main] WARN  com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI - Could not find jfxrt.jar. Internal browser will be disabled.
SoapUI 5.4.0 TestCase Runner
    12:49:06,878 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] Creating new settings at [/root/soapui-settings.xml]
    12:49:07,792 INFO  [PluginManager] 0 plugins loaded in 2 ms
    12:49:07,792 INFO  [DefaultSoapUICore] All plugins loaded
    12:49:08,652 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/tmp/soapui-project.xml]
    12:49:08,657 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI tests in project [Sample REST Project]
    12:49:08,658 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running Project [Sample REST Project], runType = SEQUENTIAL
    12:49:08,669 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [accountcreation TestCase]
    12:49:08,675 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [View Form]
    12:49:08,749 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection closed
    12:49:08,749 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down
    12:49:08,752 ERROR [WsdlSubmit] Exception in request: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
    12:49:08,764 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused], see error log for details
    12:49:08,770 ERROR [SoapUITestCaseRunner] View Form failed, exporting to [/opt/bin/Test_account_creation-accountcreation_TestCase-View_Form-0-FAILED.txt]
    12:49:08,772 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [accountcreation TestCase], time taken: 0ms, status: FAILED
    12:49:08,773 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Project [Sample REST Project] finished with status [FAILED] in 110ms
    12:49:08,773 ERROR [SoapUITestCaseRunner] java.lang.Exception: TestCase [accountcreation TestCase] failed without assertions

    12:49:08,773 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [TestCase [accountcreation TestCase] failed without assertions
], see error log for details
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:290)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.submitRequest(WsdlSubmit.java:79)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRequest.submit(RestRequest.java:192)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.RestTestRequestStep.run(RestTestRequestStep.java:794)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:211)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:47)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:138)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:46)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:363)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:273)
    ... 24 more
java.lang.Exception: TestCase [accountcreation TestCase] failed without assertions

    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.throwFailureException(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:519)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.runRunner(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:435)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:202)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.run(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:137)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.AbstractSoapUIRunner.runFromCommandLine(AbstractSoapUIRunner.java:112)
    at com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner.main(SoapUITestCaseRunner.java:122)
```

Do I need to have SoapUI downloaded somewhere in the VM i'm trying to run the docker container from? Also, I have no /opt/SoapUI folder in the VM i'm running the container from, is that something I should add in?

Comment: Can you check this docker image of soapui - https://hub.docker.com/r/nmrao/soapui

Comment: When I checked the image by running it I ended up with the same error as mentioned above, even after using the same xml project given my the author himself.
https://github.com/ddavison/docker-soapui
this is the github link to the dockerfile and project.
Also, the [file:/tmp/soapui-project.xml] is the location inside the container where project is being copied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this way of running SoapUI projects, but I think it looks like you aren't running what you think you are running...

Your parameters point to a "Sample-REST-Project-soapui-project.xml" project, but in the output, it states that:

```
12:49:08,652 INFO  [WsdlProject] Loaded project from [file:/tmp/soapui-project.xml]
```

You also give the parameter http://localhost:3000/ which I assume is the endpoint...? But in the output, you get the error message

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
```

I assume they should be the same?

Comment: I'm not sure why it says the 'Loaded project from [file:/tmp/soapui-project.xml]' but it does grab the correct project I want to test because the SoapUITestCaseRunner points to the correct project. As for the endpoint, I think it is trying to connect to http://localhost:8080 because that is the part of the URI given in the project. So, I think it should be connecting to the localhost:8080 to run the soapui tests

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. Have you found any solution ?